# tomcat 6: accessing web app without war name in the URL and without overwriting ROOT?

Tags: url, web-applications, tomcat6, context.xml

in my war's `META-INF/context.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/foobar" docBase="my-long-war-name"/>
```

I deploy my war to the webapps/ directory and I confirm that my contex.xml is in  `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\Catalina\localhost` with the name `my-long-war-name.xml`

Now, instead of accessing my REST service through `http:/ /localhost:8080/my-long-war-name/contacts/data` tomcat should allow `http:/ /localhost:8080/foobar/contacts/data`
but I can only access my service through the former URL. It's as if it completely ignores the path given above for my web app. I even tried omitting `docBase` and that didn't work either.

why doesn't this work?! it's supposed to be so basic!

Comment: Due to limitations in Tomcat, you can't do that without editing server.xml and specifying the Context element there. In your case, the path element is just silently ignored.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems correct even though Tomcat 5.5 amd 6.0 documentation says it's not a good practice to add this to server.xml. I just think the context.xml functionality doesn't always work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need the `<Context>`.  I never touch that when deploying to Tomcat, and everything works fine.

Why don't you just make the WAR name foobar, deploy it, and be done with it?  You seem to be wedded to this idea in spite of the evidence to the contrary about how basic it is.

Comment: renaming the war file will remove information from the war file name such as version number which may be helpful to the system adminitrator without having to look inside the war file.

Comment: Sounds like a poor solution.  The version info ought to be inside the war manifest.  And your build system would be a better source for version info than the name of the war.